# Unable to retrieve the value of `software.acceptance` for `EsxCli` using Powercli

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, vsphere, powercli, esxi

I am trying to retrieve the value of `software.acceptance` for `EsxCli` using the command:

```
$AcceptLevel = (Get-EsxCli -VMHost $serverhostname).software.acceptance.get()
```

However, I am getting the below error

```
Object of type 'InternalVimApi_50.ManagedObjectReference' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $AcceptLevel = (Get-EsxCli -VMHost $serverhostname).software.acceptan ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you looking for acceptance level of a specific host then you can try the following commands

$AcceptLevel = Get-EsxCli -VMhost $myhost[0]

====================================================

$AcceptLevel.software.acceptance.get() - Same as the command you provided.

====================================================

PowerCLI C:> Connect-VIServer -Server hostname

Name                           Port  User
----                           ----  ----

## XXXX

PowerCLI C:> Get-VMhost

Name                 ConnectionState PowerState 
----                 --------------- ----------

## XXXX   Connected       PoweredOn      20

PowerCLI C:> $myhost = Get-VMHost

====================================================

PowerCLI C:> $myhost[0]

Name                 ConnectionState PowerState   MemoryUsageGB
----                 --------------- ----------   -------------
XXXX   Connected       PoweredOn      20

PowerCLI C:> $acceptance = Get-EsxCli -VMHost $myhost[0]

====================================================

PowerCLI C:> $acceptance.software.acceptance.get()
PartnerSupported

====================================================

Comment: I am getting an error `Get-EsxCli : 6/25/2018 3:07:02 PM Get-EsxCli  VMHost parameter: Could not find any of the objects specified by name. 
At line:1 char:16
+ $AcceptLevel = Get-EsxCli -VMhost $serverhostname[0]
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (VMware.VimAutom...VMHost[] VMHost:RuntimePropertyInfo) [Get-EsxCli], ObnRecordProcessingFailedEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_ObnSelector_SetNewParameterValue_ObjectNotFoundCritical,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.EsxCli. 
   GetEsxCli`

Comment: Probably something is missing. I have added the commands to my earlier answer.

Comment: just put $serverhostname in your instance, not [0]